# Phalcon framework setting up project to local xampp from bit bucket

Tags: php, database, configuration, frameworks, phalcon

hi i have cloned the project files and  i have installed phalcon framework in xampp with version. i can see in php info as phalcon installed.

when i browse the project i overcome with this issue how can i resolve it.

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Database::allow($roleName, $resourceName, $access)
>   must be compatible with Phalcon\Acl\AdapterInterface::allow($roleName,
>   $resourceName, $access, $func = NULL) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\uvix1\uvix.co\common\incubator\Library\Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Database.php
>   on line 33

This my database.php code:

```
<?php
    namespace Phalcon\Acl\Adapter;

    use Phalcon\Db;
    use Phalcon\Acl\Adapter;
    use Phalcon\Acl\AdapterInterface;
    use Phalcon\Acl\Exception;
    use Phalcon\Acl\Resource;
    use Phalcon\Acl;
    use Phalcon\Acl\Role;
    class Database extends Adapter implements AdapterInterface //this is line 33
    {
        protected $options;
```

Comment: The error says that your method `Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Database::allow` doesn't have the same parameters as `Phalcon\Acl\AdapterInterface::allow`. The last one has the parameter `$func` which the first one doesn't have.

Comment: @Timothy how can i resolve this error

Comment: Find a more stable version of incubator, edit the AdapterInterface's allow method signature to include the `$func = NULL` or edit the Database's allow method to exclude it so it matches the interface.

Comment: The `$func` was added to the `allow` method in Phalcon 3.0. Updating your incubator to the latest version should resolve this issue

Comment: Update incubator, that's it.

Comment: @Timothy can you please tell how can i update incubator.?

Comment: How did you install it? with composer or did you just download the files from [github](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator)? If you used composer, just update the require package to `"phalcon/incubator": "~3.0"` and run the `composer update` command in your project root. Or else just redownload the files from the github link.

Comment: source from bit bucket ..........and i installed palcon framework from `https://phalconphp.com/en/download/windows`

Comment: Where did you get the code in `database.php`?

Comment: actually its a live site we need to enhance according to requirement and we cloned it to our localhost . we use xampp . we got database.php from that cloned source files.

Comment: Is there an `allow` method in that file? If so, just add the `$func = null` parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126897/discussion-between-abdul-waheed-and-timothy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in `database.php` is from Phalcon v2. And you are working with Phalcon v3 on your XAMPP setup.
v2 and v3 have lots of API changes and the errors your are getting are because of this.

You have 2 options here.

1. Lots of work: Upgrade all of your code to make it Phalcon v3 compatible. And upgrade your Phalcon version on your production environment to Phalcon v3.
2. Easier fix: Downgrade your Phalcon version on your XAMPP to Phalcon v2.